# Why array_values is better than a foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

Why `array_values()` is better than a foreach loop to re-index an array?

**Example 1:**

```
$arrays = [
  1 => '0',
  2 => '1',
  3 => '2',
  4 => '3',
  5 => '',
  6 => '',
  7 => '7',
  8 => [
    0 => 'toto',
    1 => 'manu',
    2 => 'noé',
    3 => 'david'
  ]
];

$arrayNonAssoc = [];
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
     $arrayNonAssoc[] = $array;
}
```

So the **Example 1** is the error to not do and...

**Example 2:**

```
$arrays = [
  1 => '0',
  2 => '1',
  3 => '2',
  4 => '3',
  5 => '',
  6 => '',
  7 => '7',
  8 => [
    0 => 'toto',
    1 => 'manu',
    2 => 'noé',
    3 => 'david'
  ]
];

var_dump(array_values($arrays));
```

I have read about it, but I didn't found any explications to this. Both **Example 1** and **Example 2** return the same result...

Is it about performance?

Comment: Besides the fact that your array is invalid (you have 2 entries with key `7`), it depends on circumstance... but generally speaking, for smaller arrays, `array_values()` is a single function call, rather than a block of code using foreach.... one function call compared with a loop and an assignment

Comment: There is no rule, guidance, advice, or best practices telling anyone to use `array_values()` rather than `foreach()` (or vice versa). Voting to close this question as it is not a good fit for SO: *answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*

Comment: It is not always easy to state something is 'better' or not because most of the time this is totally subjective to the context around it. If you want to know if something is better for your use case you should simply profile it. Also it is confusing to call something `arrays` when it is simply a multi-dimensional array lol.

Comment: @Stephan-v `Better` doesn't always mean performance-wise better.

Comment: You are right, I was steering in that direction because of the final question: `Is it about performances?`

Comment: Sorry for the double 7, it was a mistake. But thanks for your experience :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Less code.
2. Easier to understand code, because that's exactly what `array_values` is for, yet your `foreach` could do anything unless you read and understand it.
3. `array_values` is a native PHP function implemented in C behind the scenes, and likely much more performant than custom PHP code.