# Natsort Array and set Key Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I cannot find the answer to my question, so I try to ask it here.

I have a simple array, and I natsort it. The result is something like:

```
[0] => . 
[1] => .. 
[2] => cap.1 
[13] => cap.2 
[21] => cap.3 
[22] => cap.4 
[23] => cap.5 
[24] => cap.6
etc...
```

Now, I need the key match the order of values, something like this:

```
[0] => . 
[1] => .. 
[2] => cap.1 
[3] => cap.2 
[4] => cap.3 
[5] => cap.4 
[6] => cap.5 
[7] => cap.6
etc...
```

Is it possible with a `foreach` cycle?

Comment: is **WHAT**  possible with a foreach cycle?

Comment: @RiggsFolly `array_values` is far better than `foreach`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218464/why-array-values-is-better-than-a-foreach/

Comment: @akshaypjoshi That may be true. I just was not sure what the OP was actually asking!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset PHP Array Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536961/reset-php-array-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using foreach() try it like this

```
// assuming your original array is called $a
$b = [];
foreach($a as $v) $b[] = $v;

var_dump($b);
```

Even simpler is using array_values()

```
// assuming your original array is called $a
$b = array_values($a);

var_dump($b);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What i needed. Thanks!

Comment: If this solves your problem you should up vote this answer or even better mark it as accepted solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to return the values from an array with sequential indexes.

```
$a = [ 1 => 'a', 3 => 'c'];
$a = array_values($a);
print_r($a);
```

Will give...

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => c
)
```